# Angular 12/rxjs: BehaviorSubject shall return empty object array, but returns undefined instead

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a livesearch and want to understand three scenarios:

- no user input (if observable = undefined)
- no result found (if observable = empty array)
- results found (if observable = non-empty array)

The trouble is my behaviour subject which holds the resultset recognizes an empty array as "undefined".

```js
  loc$ = new BehaviorSubject<SearchResult[] | undefined>(undefined);
  searchLocation$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  initModule(): void {
    this.searchLocation$.pipe(
      switchMap((searchTerm: string) => this.fetchLocation(searchTerm)),
    ).subscribe(locations => {
      console.log(locations); //undefined if empty array `of([])` returned!! ;((
      this.loc$.next(locations);
    });

  }

  searchLocation(incSearchTerm: string): void {
    this.searchLocation$.next(incSearchTerm);
  }

  fetchLocation(incSearchTerm: string): Observable<SearchResult[] | undefined> {
    if (!incSearchTerm) {
      // if no search term, return undefined
      return of(undefined);
    }

    return this.httpHandler.getLocations(incSearchTerm).pipe(
      tap(searchResults => {
        if (searchResults ) {
          return searchResults ;
        } else {
          // if no results, return empty array -- this does not work
          return of([]);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

So whenever I return `of([])` in hope to return an empty array, I always receive an "undefined" value.

How can I correctly do one of the following:

- recognize `of([])` as empty array
- return another observable as empty array
- or determine the three scenarios with a different approach altogether.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be trying to return from within a `tap`. That return will be ignored. Maybe you wanted `map`?

Comment: Returning a value from `tap()` doesn't change the `next` value going through. Maybe you want to use `map()` )then you don't need `of()`) or `switchMap()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted use *map* instead of *tap* to return values from getLocations.  The **map** operator transforms the emitted value, while **tap** performs a side-effect. Also you can use the nullish coalescing operator (??) instead of using an if statement to make your code a little more compact.

```
fetchLocation(incSearchTerm: string): Observable<SearchResult[] | undefined> {
  if (!incSearchTerm) {
    return of(undefined);
  }
  return this.httpHandler.getLocations(incSearchTerm).pipe(
    map(searchResults => searchResults ?? [])
  );
}
```